# How to get site collections URL, title, site owners and site admins through Powershell on SP2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I am able to return for "sitecollectionURL" the primary and secondary admins using the followins PS:

```
Get-SPSite "sitecollectionURL" | foreach-object{ Write-host $_.Url - $_.RootWeb.Title - $_.Owner.Name - $_.SecondaryContact.Name}
```

but what I really want is all the ones listed on site settings > site collection owners group (different than primary and secondary site collection admin) and also the site settings > site collection administrators.

Answer (score 3):

No need to have a query for finding the owners group.

If you do not know the name of "owners group", the web by default gives you the property **$web.associatedownersgroup** .

This returns the owners group .

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to the **Site Collection Owners** group?

In that case, use the following:

```
$web = get-spweb "RootWeb Url"
$web.Groups | Where {$_.Name -eq "Site Collection Owners"} | select Users
```

To get the Site Collection Administrators, use the following (`$web` has the same value as above):

```
$web.SiteAdministrators
```

Edit:
If you do not know the name of the Owners group, you can still retrieve the groups that have Full Control access on the site, which usually includes the "Owners" (here `$web` has the same value as above):

```
$web.Groups | ?{$_.Roles.Name -contains "Full Control"}  | select Name,Roles
```

Comment: Thank you Chris Odegard, it works if I know the Site Collection Owners group name, but if I don't know it then how can I get it? Should the approach then will be to get all people who have full control permissions to the site collection? How to do that with PS?

Comment: For SiteAdministrators the sentence returned with no results

Comment: @MLC That may work, assuming there are not a lot of groups with Full Control on the Site:

$web.Groups | ?{$_.Roles.Name -contains "Full Control"}  | select Name,Roles

Comment: @MLC re: Site Administrators, are you sure that the group is populated? Check here: https://<Root Web URL>/_layouts/15/mngsiteadmin.aspx
Also, where are you running PowerShell?